# iOS - Too many header files in AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, delegates, header

I was just wondering if it's considered bad practice to have a large number of header files imported into an AppDelegate?

My game has a lot of views (in separate .xib files) that the AppDelegate switches between. At the moment, I am importing 16 header files in my AppDelegate.h file, but is there a better way to manage all of this? Most sample code I've seen has a maximum of around 4 or 5 header files.

Thanks!

Comment: "is it considered bad practice to have a large number of header files imported into an AppDelegate?" - no, its not bad practice; import what you need, nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 1):

It's usually better practice to forward declare your classes in the header file, and then import their headers in your implementation file, for example:

```
// .h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class MyView;
@class MyOtherView;
@class MyOtherOtherView;

@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>


@property (strong, nonatomic) MyView *myView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) MyOtherView *myOtherView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) MyOtherOtherView *myOtherOtherView;

@end


// .m

#import "MyAppDelegate.h"

#import "MyView.h"
#import "MyOtherView.h"
#import "MyOtherOtherView.h"


@implementation MyAppDelegate

@synthesize myView;
@synthesize myOtherView;
@synthesize myOtherOtherView;


// methods

@end
```

Doing this will help to avoid situations where you will end up with circular `#import` references.

I will also often create a header file simply for importing other header files for clarity, e.g. `#import "MyViews.h"`

Answer (score 0):

Sample code is just that -- *sample* code, usually meant to clearly demonstrate a single concept. Don't expect your application to look like sample code if it does more than one single relatively simple thing. Expect it to look more like several dozen sample projects all put together (although I wouldn't advise doing exactly that!).